# What exactly are βροτολοιγῶ?

Tags: vocabulary, greek, mythology

From Procopius's *Secret History* (or *Arcana Historia*) XII.12-14:

> Διὸ δὴ ἐμοί τε καὶ τοῖς πολλοῖς ἠμῶν οὐδεπώποτε ἔδοξαν οὗτοι ἄνθρωποι εἶναι, ἀλλὰ δαίμονες παλαμναῖοί τινες καὶ ὥσπερ οἱ ποιηταὶ λέγουσι βροτολοιγῶ ἤστην…

(Trans. mine)

> And thus to me, and to many others of us, they [Emperor Justinian and his wife Theodora] never seemed to be humans, but rather to be some sort of murderous demons, and even akin to two of those things that the poets call *brotoloigoi*…

What are those things the poets call *brotoloigoi*? L&S translate the word as "bane of men" and cite it applied to Arēs, Apollōn, and Erōs, but it doesn't seem like Procopius is comparing Justinian to a deity here: it sounds like some sort of monster instead.

Comment: Montanari translates it as "deadly for mortals."

Comment: @AlexB. Sorry, I should have specified: the literal meaning (brotos + loigos) makes sense, I'm just curious why Procopius would use it in this way when L&S only list it as a divine epithet. I'm wondering if there's some other usage of it, perhaps to describe the Furies instead of something like Erōs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Diccionario Griego-Español is more complete than Liddell-Scott, but only goes up to epsilon:

[http://dge.cchs.csic.es/xdge/βροτολοιγός](http://dge.cchs.csic.es/xdge/%CE%B2%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%84%CE%BF%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%B9%CE%B3%CF%8C%CF%82)

> *funesto para los mortales* epít. de Ares Il.5.31, Od.8.115, Hes.Sc.333, Tyrt.1.47, A.Supp.665, Sch.D.T.234.14, Corn.ND 21, de Eros AP 5.180 (Mel.), 12.37 (Diosc.), de Eris, Timo SHell.795, cóm. de un pederasta o fellator Ar.Fr.969.

Ares, Eros, Eris (but in the Supplementum Hellenisticum, so obscure), and as a condemnation of sexual deviancy (but in a fragment of Aristophanes, so again unlikely to be known by Procopius).

I think it's likeliest that Procopius is referring to the Homeric and Hesiodic usage of *brotoloigos* as an epithet of Ares (which is the usage ascribed to "poets"). The reason he can still use an epithet of Ares to refer to Justinian is simple: as far as any Christian of the time was concerned, the ancient Greek gods *were* demons. And a comparison of a Christian emperor to Ares would certainly not have been intended as complimentary.

The picture is complicated by Procopius' [apparent scepticism towards Christian mores](https://markmperry.wordpress.com/2012/01/01/the-religious-outlook-of-procopius-a-critical-assessment-of-the-scholarship/), particularly in the *Secret History*; but I don't think we need to posit that Procopius is aware of referents of *brotoilogos* that we are not.